# Database design for a particular sales order scenario

Tags: sql, database, crm

Please refer to the database design below:

[image]

Consider a scenario where a sales order is created based on the prodcuts in the 'Product' table. But if the price of any product changes, then the price should not be updated in any sales orders created in the past. That price should only be used for new sales orders. What do I need to do to take care of this kinda situation?

Comment: make sure you pick the answer you decide to go with. Thanks, and good luck.

Comment: @Andy I'm still a little confused. But I'll pick an answer soon. Just trying to analyze whats the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Cost and Price to the SalesOrderProduct table, and set them during the initial append of that table.

Comment: Product holds the current price and is used in constructing each new sales order.  Once the sale is made, you want to hold the price of the product for that order.  Sticking "the price at the time" in SalesOrderProduct seems reasonable, but I will want to see what others say.  Is productid needed in salesorder if the total for the order is going to be constructed from salesorderproduct?

Comment: Thats understandable in a situation when you know only one item will be bought per transaction. I am now confused as I do not see how it would take into account a sale with multiple items. Example, if I bought a shirt and shoes, this schema would not work because it would take it as two separate orders, instead of a single order.

Comment: @andy  couldn't you have record1: salesorderid1, productid1 (shoes), shoeprice; record2:salesorderid1, prodctid2 (shirt), shirtprice; etc? then the sum for the order is the sum of the price field for the items on that order.

Comment: @andy you're assuming that Salesorder to SalesOrderProduct is one-to-one join, and I'm assuming that SalesOrderProducts sole purpose is the be a one-to-many join, otherwise SaleOrder could be joined directly to Product.

Comment: Technically yes, in this schema, no. Notice that it is a primary key, which means it can't be duplicated in SalesOrder. So in your example, salesorderid could never duplicate within salesorderproduct with different products if that makes sense.

Comment: SalesOrderProduct does not contain any primary keys, and thus, can contain multiple records...

Comment: @JohnEasley I see what you are saying, so we are just thinking it differently. That makes sense. I just really wanted to know because I could not see it for the life of me. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I think that is why I was suggesting pulling productid from the salesorder table and computing your salesorder total from the cost at the time shoved into salesorderproduct, if i follow your thinking.

Comment: @JohnEasley Could you just explain how you would implement multiple items from a single order using this schema?

Comment: Yea @mikeY To me the way its set up, it can't handle what I am saying. But again, if that is the point of this table, then yes, this still works great.

Comment: @Andy, in a one to many between SalesOrder and SalesOrderProduct, multiple items would be added to SalesOrderProduct with lookup fields for all remaining fields in Product.  I'm not understanding the confusion here? There would be one sales order, and multiple products attached to the sales order via SalesOrderProduct which is then joined to Product.  The remaining fields in Product would be lookup fields in SalesOrderProduct.  He could rename Product.Cost/Price to Product.CurrentCost/Price for comparison to selling price later.

Comment: @mikey yeah, productID can be removed from SalesOrder.

Answer (score 1):

Your going to want a separate table to hold total orders. You'll only be holding individual item orders of a single row. Seeing as the salesorder is the primary key, you can't tell if there are groups of items in the same order. Just use the primary key from totalorder and reference it to another table that can group everything that belonged in one order. But if this is the functionality you want, then what John Easley said works fine.

Comment: SalesOrderProduct can handle multiple products (records)

Comment: @Andy I don't follow. So, are you saying I need a seperate table if I want to have one or more sales orders under the same sales order id, I need a seperate table. If not, I can just use John Easley's solution?

Comment: John, how does it handle it if it exists solely to link the product and sales order. Each individual sales order will be unique, and hence so will salesorderproduct, but it won't link a bunch of items to a single whole order. Unless I am wrong?

Comment: @mvador99 what I mean is have a ordersummary to hold ordersummaryid(PK) the total order price, userid, or whatever else you would like there for your records, and then use that ordersummaryid to group individual orders in salesorder together. So like if you ever want to know exactly how many items made up a whole total order you could, because you have them grouped by a specific order at a specific time, as well as access the cost of each at the time.

Comment: SalesOrder to SalesOrderProduct should be a one-to-many join.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I don't see how that would work out if the primary key would differentiate each individual order, not linking it in any way but an item. Could you give me an example please.